# Storing HTML Within Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping, character

I'm storing HTML code within an element attribute like so.

```
<div data-html-code="<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sNhhvQGsMEc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>"></div>
```

How can I escape all the necessary characters to make this valid using jQuery/Javascript?

Comment: replace double quotes with single quote or by escape them by \" \". Like this : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/c8jzo021/

Comment: use single quotes like this `<div data-html-code='<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sNhhvQGsMEc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'></div>`

Comment: How do I do this dynamically, When code is entered in an input field? Also would escaping '<', '>' also be necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this `htmlEscape` method

```
function htmlEscape(str) {
    return String(str)
            .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
            .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
            .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
            .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
            .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
```

this should give you a string that can be used as a valid html attribute value